# cant write to config with quotes

Tags: python, config

heres my code

```
import os

while True:
  print("welcome to the wget-gui configuration tool.")
  do = input("what would you like to do?\n1: configure wget url\n2: erase config file\n3")

  if do == "1":
    
    url = input("enter the wget url\n1")
    with open('config.conf', 'w') as f:
      f.write(URL="/"url/"")
    print("configuration success")
    run = input("would you like to run the script? y/n>")
    if run == "y":
      os.system("bash install.sh")
  if do == "2":
    with open('config.conf', 'w') as f:
      f.close()
    print("cleared!")
```

i tried `f.write("''",url,"''")` and other methods that i saw but it didn't work. I kept getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/wget-gui/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    f.write(URL="" + (url) + "")
TypeError: TextIOWrapper.write() takes no keyword arguments
```

i tried using os.system but i couldnt get the variables from the python file.

Comment: `f.write("'" + url + "'")`

Comment: Why do you want quotes in the file instead of just the URL?

Comment: Why are you using `wget` from python? It has a built-in `requests` library that you can use to make HTTP requests.

Comment: If you really want to execute `wget` from python, use `subprocess.run()`. You don't need to quote arguments explicitly.

Comment: You're trying to pass the keyword argument `URL=` to `write()`, but it does not know about any such argument.  You can't just pass random keyword args to functions.

Comment: `f.write(f'URL="{url}"')` is probably what you are wanting, but what you *need* is the `requests` module :^)